# Scraping an ajax website using Python requests

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a webpage that load is content after 5 seconds.
I want to use the lib requests.
Is there something to make the request wait?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from time import sleep

link = 'https://www.off---white.com'
while True:
    try:
        r = requests.get(link, stream=False, timeout=8)
        break
    except:
        if r.status_code == 404:
            print("Client error")
            r.raise_for_status()
        sleep(1)


page = soup(r.text, "html.parser")

products = page.findAll('article', class_='product')
titles = page.findAll('span', class_='prod-title')[0].text.strip()
images= page.findAll('img', class_="js-scroll-gallery-snap-target")

for product in products:
    print(product)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ever answer such question but the asker give a better answer `cfscrape` , `cfscrape` is better than `selenium` in this website. btw the question seem to be closed i dont know why.

```
import cfscrape
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://www.off---white.com"
headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20180101 Firefox/47.0",
    "Referer" : url
}
session = requests.session()
scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(sess=session)
link = 'https://www.off---white.com'
r = scraper.get(link, headers=headers)
page = soup(r.text, "html.parser")
```

> update at 15/4/2020

Since off-white updated his protection, `cfscrape` is not a good idea for now. plz try to use selenium.

To kind of this questions, i can not give a answer that work forever. They keep updating their protection!

Comment: for me. it is the same result as OP answer

Answer (score 1):

No, the content that is received will be always be the same, you have to prerender it by yourself to fetch final version of the webpage.

You have to use a headless browser to execute the javascript on the webpage.

**Prerender.IO** offers pretty much what you need, you can check it out, the setup is pretty simple.

```
const prerender = require('prerender');
const server = prerender();
server.start();
```